# pcl Get the PointCloudCoherence to compute likelihood --> How to compute likelihood

Tags: c++, tracking, point-cloud-library

I am using the pcl [tracking code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/tracking.php) under PCL 1.7 and I currently track a ball. It works however if the ball is outside the tracked area and I put it inside again the particle tracking tracks any other cloud and does not find the ball anymore.

That is why I would like to check online if the current particle cloud still matches from its color and its distances to the once initialized point cloud.

Therefore I thought using this function [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/tracking.php):

```
CloudCoherencePtr   getCloudCoherence () const
    Get the PointCloudCoherence to compute likelihood. More...
```

Here it says that with this Coherence I can compute a likelihood....

My Questions:

1) What is a Coherence in particular? And what is the:

-HSVColorCoherence
-DistanceCoherence

2) How exactly can I compute the likelihood and what likelihood is that? Is this the likelihood how good the once initialized point cloud matches by its color and its distance the current tracked particles? Cause this is what I want.